# how to set loop inside append. This gives a Syntax Error

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: true,
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" +
    "index.php/admin/get_user_privilages",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    user_id: user_id
  },
  success: function(res) {

    $.each(res, function(key, value) {


      $('#image_view_panel').append(
        '<div class="col-md-6">' +
        '<div class="checbox-wrapper">' +
        '<div class="checbox-wrapper-heading">' +
        '<h5>' + value.category_name + '</h5>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="checbox-wrapper-label">'
        $.each(value.sub_cat, function(key2, value2) {
          +
          '<label> <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks"> &nbsp;' +
          value2 + '</label>'
        }); +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'

      );


    });

  },
  error: function(data) {

  }

});
```

Comment: Use variable to append string and same for loop then later append to panel.

Comment: I need to set a loop inside a loop. it is ok without append function. But when I set second loop inside append function it show syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using variable, keep it simple.

```
var iHtml = '';
$.each(res, function(key, value) {
  iHtml += '<div class="col-md-6">' +
    '<div class="checbox-wrapper">' +
    '<div class="checbox-wrapper-heading">' +
    '<h5>' + value.category_name + '</h5>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="checbox-wrapper-label">';
  $.each(value.sub_cat, function(key2, value2) {
    iHtml +=
      '<label> <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks"> &nbsp;' +
      value2 + '</label>';
  });
  iHtml += '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
});

$('#image_view_panel').append(iHtml);
```